# Hibernate One to One relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, relational-database, one-to-one, hibernate-annotations

suppose we have a class called `LatLng`:

```
public class LatLng {

    private long id;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    //setters & getters

}
```

as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

we have a one-to-one relationship between `PoliceStation` and `LatLng`

and one-to-one relationship between `Hotel` and `LatLng`

and so on...

how can we create such a relationship in hibernate? (both annotation and xml-mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a bidirectional one-to-one association between your entities.

Check these links:

[Hibernate - bidirectional @OneToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044567/hibernate-bidirectional-onetoone)

[Hibernate bidirectional using mapping files.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-bidirectional-121)

Follow the links and try to create your entities.